# Deploy third party jar as if it is a projects own built jar?

Tags: maven

I have to use a company-proprietary jar generator to build a library which I need to publish to a maven repo. My workflow looks like this:

1. Use jar generator to generate the JAR and export it to my filesystem. Name this Jar GenLib.jar
2. Make a project that looks like:
   ExtProj
   ExtProj/lib/Genlib.jar
   Extproj/pom.xml
3. pom.xml has the following content:

```html
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
     <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
     <artifactId>EXTProj</artifactId>
        <packaging>jar</packaging>
     <build>
      <plugins>
       <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
        <executions>
         <execution>
          <id>install-extlib</id>
          <phase>install</phase>
          <goals>
           <goal>install-file</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
           <file>${project.basedir}/lib/EXTLib.jar</file>
           <groupId>com.mycompany.EXTLib</groupId>
           <artifactId>EXTLib</artifactId>
           <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
           <packaging>jar</packaging>
          </configuration>
         </execution>
        </executions>
       </plugin>
      </plugins>
     </build>
    </project>
```

4. I can run mvn install to install the file to my local maven repo.

However, I also want to run mvn deploy to deploy that same jar to my remote repo. How do I do that? From what I can see in the mavne deploy plugin, this is not possible. I can use mvn [deploy deploy-file](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-remote.html) but it requires me to type the project artifactId, group Id, etc every time I deploy. I want it to use the info in the pom.xml. Ideally, the remote repo should contain com.mycompany:EXTProj:1.0.0 or com.mycompany:EXTLib:1.0.0.

Comment: You can configure the `deploy-file` analogously to the `install-file`.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the deploy plugin to provide the maven coordinates (more information can be found here https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-file-mojo.html ) and the file name definition with in the pom itself  and invoke it to the install phase , maven profile should be helpful in achieving this task.